# How can I stop other functions from interfering with a click event?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make three separate pieces of content appear on the basis of a click event. This works, however if the user clicks more than one button in sequence, both pieces of content appear at once.

My knowledge of JS is limited. I know that another 'else' condition might help me but when I add it, the whole function stops working.

I want only one content option to be visible at one time. Is there a way I can add an additional condition in my function declaration to do this? Thank you for any help.

```css
.container-top {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.tab {
  border: 2px solid #DCDCDC;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-top">

  <button onclick="productDrop()" class="tab" >
    <span class="tab-title">Product description</span>
  </button>

  <button onclick="financeDrop()" class="tab" id="finance">
    <span class="tab-title">Interest-free finance</span>
  </button>


  <button onclick="deliveryDrop()"class="tab" id="delivery">
    <span class="tab-button">Delivery and returns</span>
  </button>

</div>


<div id="productBody">
Product
</div>

<div id="financeBody">
Finance 
</div>

<div id="deliveryBody">
Delivery 
</div>

<script>
function productDrop() {
  var x = document.getElementById("productBody");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function financeDrop() {
  var x = document.getElementById("financeBody");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function deliveryDrop() {
  var x = document.getElementById("deliveryBody");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen instead when more than one button is clicked?

Comment: There are a lot of ways you could implement this, but a common way to add "radio button" functionality (that is, you only want _one thing_ at a time) is to always hide everything when you initially click (even if some things are already hidden), and then show the one item you do want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overthinking it. Let's consolidate and accomplish the same goal:

```js
const blah = document.getElementById('displayArea');

blah.innerHTML = 'Product'; // First Default.

drop = (id) => {
  blah.innerHTML = id;
}
```

```css
.container-top {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.tab {
  border: 2px solid #DCDCDC;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-top">

  <button onclick="drop('Product')" class="tab" autofocus>
    <span class="tab-title">Product description</span>
  </button>

  <button onclick="drop('Finance')" class="tab">
    <span class="tab-title">Interest-free finance</span>
  </button>


  <button onclick="drop('Delivery')"class="tab">
    <span class="tab-button">Delivery and returns</span>
  </button>

</div>


<h1 id="displayArea"></h1>
```